# Prestashop: check if some core file was modified

Tags: prestashop, e-commerce, prestashop-1.7

I have a legacy Prestashop 1.7.2.2 installation and I would like to know if some core file was modified compared with the original version.
I have to move, upgrade and fix some issue in this installation but if someone modified the original core files I can find difficulties or the website could rise errors.

Do you know some method to smartly do this check?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the original files? Then all you need to do is compare the directories and files with the right tool. I would use [Total Commander](https://www.ghisler.com/) and it's "Synchronize dirs" command. You can have original files on your local computer and compare them over FTP with you server files.

You can also use [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) but you can only compare local directories so you'll need to download your Prestashop install from the server.

Comment: original files are those of a fresh prestashop installation. Yes, I can do a fresh install of the same version, donwload the legacy version and do a diff on the dirs, but this is a huge work...

Comment: You don't have to download the legacy version if you use Total Commander. [Synchronize directories](https://www.ghisler.ch/wiki/index.php/Synchronize_directories) works over FTP.

Answer (score 0):

In admin You go on information page under ***"Advance Parameter"*** menu. IN the last box you will see  ***"List of changed files"***

Comment: I thank you, but that page assert there is not any file modification, but I'm sure there is. Do you know how this check is done?

Answer (score 0):

1) Download a fresh version of 1.7.2.2 from PrestaShop.com.  Let's call this directory $BASE.

2) Download the files for your cart.  Let's call this directory $YOUR_CART.

3) Compare $BASE to $YOUR_CART.  This will show you changes in core.

```
cd $BASE
for i in `find . -type f`
do
  diff -q $i $YOUR_CART/$i
done
```

4) Do the same thing in reverse, to find files that have been added to your installation that are not in $BASE.

```
cd $YOUR_CART
for i in `find . -type f`
do
  diff -q $i $BASE/$i 2>>/tmp/newfiles
done
```

Now the file `/tmp/newfiles` has a list of additions that have been made in your installation.